# Why is (Yosemite) Mac Mail hitting my internet so hard?

Tags: mail.app, macos

Mail is downloading 250-500Kb/sec and has been for a while now. I can't figure out what it's doing. Is there some way to find out? I tried Window->Activity but it didn't show anything being downloaded.

Comment: If Window Activity shows nothing how are you sure that it is Mail downloading could it be something else?

Answer (score 1):

How about using [opensnoop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/opensnoop.1m.html) to try to work out what Mail is doing? opensnoop is one of the tools that make up the Dtrace toolkit. It is part of the OS.

```
sudo opensnoop | grep Mail
```

That command should show you what files Mail is opening. That might point you in the right direction to what it is doing.